# Why is there a word boundary in “ßv”?

Tags: font-encodings, ligatures

I have made a blackletter font (http://www.linta.de/Jena1330, although this may instead be a generic thing, which just usually does not show up due to absence of initial and final replacements) for use with LaTeX, which contains some initial forms. Most things work well, but there is a substitution

```
 (LABEL BOUNDARYCHAR)
  (LIG O 166 O 27)
```

in the pl file of the font (`O 27` is a swashy initial `O 166 = C v`) which is applied also in the case of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{jena1330}
\begin{document}
 \textjena{ßvi}
\end{document}
```

(`\textjena` is defined in the `jena1330` package to use that font.) Furthermore, `œvi` has no substitution as expected, and with `\DeclareTextSymbol{\aaa}{T1}{97}`, `\aaa{}vi` has the substitution, as opposed to what I'd like to see. The final substitution ſ→s does not occur for the case of `ſœ` and `ſ\aaa`, but `sß` is also problematic.

How can I make sure that there are no in all these cases?

---

The reason I want this is because in some cases („Inhaltsverzeichnis”) I want to typeset a round s in the middle of the word, but the v after it should not be substituted to initial form. So I tried to build a glyph `\DeclareTextSymbol{\zwj}{T1}{12}` (zero width, without special initial or final substitutions) to be able to type `Inhalts\/\zwj{}verzeichnis` in this case and get what I want. However, this behaves just as the `\aaa` in the minimal example above and therefore does not solve the problem. I solved this original problem using a random ascii non-letter character to define the symbol and it now works with `\DeclareTextSymbol{\*}{T1}{12}` as wished, but word boundaries in LaTeX are still a mystery to me, as already in [Dealing with word boundaries in a pl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79647/dealing-with-word-boundaries-in-a-pl-file)

*I'm not sure about tags, feel free to retag this question if there are better fitting tags.*

Comment: The original issue is gone due to `Inhalts\/\*verzeichnis`, but I still have a lack of knowledge.